# No consigo agrupar resultados en MYSQL aplicando inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

Estoy usando la BBDD '***world***' de ejemplo de MySQL, para elaborar una una consulta que resuelva la siguiente pregunta: "*¿Cómo puedes averiguar el número de habitantes de cualquier país
que no reside en una ciudad?*"

Que resuelvo correctamente si lo hago así:

```
select city.countrycode, country.population - sum(city.population) as poblacionrural from city, country where city.countrycode=country.code group by countrycode limit 10;
```

[image: consulta01]

Sin embargo, si trato de resolverla utilizando la sentencia INNER JOIN para practicar, no lo consigo. Me da error cuando trato de agrupar por código de país con GROUP BY:

```
select B.countrycode, A.country_pop-sum(B.city_pop) as poplacionrural
from
(select countrycode, sum(population) as city_pop from city) B
INNER JOIN
(select code, population as country_pop from country) A
ON B.countrycode=A.code
GROUP BY B.countrycode;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la segunda imagen, recibo el mismo error sino pongo el GROUP BY.

¿Cómo puedo usar el GROUP BY correctamente en mi segunda consulta con INNER JOIN para que me la resuelva correctamente?

Por favor, necesito ayuda ya que no doy con la solución...

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: no me suena nada bien esas subconsultas en el from. Yo solo he visto los inner join directamente con tablas. Seria algo como `select B.countrycode, A.country_pop-sum(B.city_pop) as poplacionrural FROM city AS B INNER JOIN country as A on B.countryCode=A.code GROUP BY B.countrycode;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De la [documentación de MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html):

> MySQL >= 5.7.5 implementan la detección de dependencia funcional. Si el modo SQL ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY está habilitado (que es por defecto), MySQL rechaza las consultas para las cuales la lista de selección, la condición HAVING o la lista ORDER BY se refieren a columnas no agregadas que no están nombradas en la cláusula GROUP BY ni son funcionalmente dependientes de ellas.

El error que te muestra es porque en la subquery B estás utilizando la función de agregación `SUM()` sin agrupar (deberías agrupar por `countrycode`).

Además en la query principal estás utilizando la columna `city.countrycode` (al igual que la columna `country.population`) en el `SELECT` pero la misma no se encuentra en la claúsula `GROUP BY`. En el caso de la columna `city.population` su utilización es correcta ya que estás utiliznado la función de agregación `SUM()`.

Además en este caso no necesitas utilzar subqueries para relacionar ambas tablas utiliznado `INNER JOIN`, la sintaxís es similar a la del producot cartesiano con where (en lugar de la coma colocas `INNER JOIN` y la condición después del `ON`, en lugar de en el where).

```
SELECT country.code, country.population - SUM(city.population) AS poblacionrural 
FROM city
INNER JOIN country ON city.countrycode = country.code
GROUP BY country.code, country.population
limit 10;
```

No conozco el modelo de datos, por lo que es dificil saber si la query es correcta, pero pareciera que si.

Comment: Gracias por tu explicación y por tu respuesta @nachospiu. Todo muy claro.

Comment: De nada @solari21!!! Me alegra que te haya sido util.